# Onitemclicklistner for spinner how to pass the id to next spinner in android

Tags: android, spinner

Hi in the below code describes the spinner .In the spinner Am displaying different types of building names for calling the Api. Based on the response I am setting the name of the building to the spinner.

From the response :
ID and Name

Now,My question is when user selected any building name from the spinner.I want to take the ID from spinner and then want to pass it to next spinner.

can any one help me how to do it.

```
   private void selectBuilding() {
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                // Write code for your refresh logic

                progressDialog = new ProgressDialog (getActivity ());
                progressDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
                progressDialog.setMessage("Communicating...");
                progressDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
                progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
                progressDialog.show();
                OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                        .connectTimeout(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                        .writeTimeout(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                        .readTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                        .build();

                Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                        .baseUrl(API.URL_BASE)
                        .addConverterFactory(ScalarsConverterFactory.create())
                        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                        .client (client)
                        .build();
                API service = retrofit.create (API.class);
                final Call<Managebuilding> userCall = service.getbuildinglist ();
                userCall.enqueue(new Callback<Managebuilding> () {

                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(Call <Managebuilding> call, Response <Managebuilding> response) {

                        if (response != null && response.code ( ) == 200 && response.isSuccessful ( )) {
                            Managebuilding building = response.body ();
                            String Name = null,Id;
                            String Lists=new Gson ( ).toJson (response.body ());
                                //  JSONArray jsonArray=new JSONArray ();
                               // JSONObject jsonObject = null;
                                try {
                                    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject (Lists);
                                    JSONArray result = jsonObject.getJSONArray ("list");
                                    System.out.println (result);
                                    //JSONArray result = jsonArray.getJSONArray ("ID");

                                    arrayList = new ArrayList <> ( );
                                    arrayList1 = new ArrayList <> ( );
                                    for (int i = 0; i <result.length(); i++) {

                                        Id=result.getJSONObject (i).getString ("ID");

                                        Name=result.getJSONObject (i).getString ("Name");

                                        arrayList.add (Name);
                                        arrayList1.add (Id);
                                    }

                                    ArrayAdapter <String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter <String> (getContext (),android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, arrayList);

                                    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

                                    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);

                                } catch (JSONException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace ( );
                            }


                            progressDialog.dismiss ( );

                        } else {
                            progressDialog.dismiss ( );
                            Log.d ("Response errorBody", String.valueOf (response.errorBody ( )));
                        }

                    }


                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(Call<Managebuilding> call, Throwable t) {
                        // lv.setAdapter (adapter);
                        System.out.println("onFailure");
                        System.out.println(t.fillInStackTrace());
                        progressDialog.dismiss();
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity (), "Some error occurred -> ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();;
                        // progressDialog.dismiss();



                    }

                });
            }


        }, 5000);
        return ;
    }
```

OnitemclickListner:

```
  spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener () {

            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                       int position, long id) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                int pos=spinner.getSelectedItemPosition ();

                String ids= String.valueOf (arrayList1.get (pos));

                //String obj;

                System.out.println (ids);
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });

    }
```

Comment: save the ID parameter in a arraylist as well. Then use the `position` parameter from the `onItemSelected` method and get the ID from the new arraylist by using position clicked.

Comment: @RahulKhurana Position of the item I am getting .but not getting the selected id from the spinner

Comment: You will get the ID from the array list of IDs. use arrayList.get(position) to get the ID

Comment: @RahulKhurana Please look into it my updated code

Comment: use `String id = arrayList1.get (position);` inside `onItemSelected`

Comment: @RahulKhurana Inside of the onItemselected only I used Right?

Comment: Yes right......

Comment: @RahulKhurana I am getting only name not 
ID

Comment: Are you using **arrayList1**  ??

Comment: update your latest code in the question.

Comment: @RahulKhurana yes I am using arrayList1

Comment: please update your code in the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First Create a Model Class like `Building`

```
public class Building{
 private String id;
 private String name:
 
 public Building(String id, String name){
  this.id = id;
  this.name = name;
 }
 
 public String getId(){
  return id;
 }
 public String getName(){
   return name;
  }
}
```

Then create an `ArrayList` Type of `Building` in your `activity` like following

```
// declear it in global scope
ArrayList<Building> buildingList;

// and initialize it in `onCreate`
buildingList = new ArrayList <> ();
```

And use this `arraylist` inside your `API` response like below.

```
userCall.enqueue(new Callback<Managebuilding> () {

   @Override
   public void onResponse(Call <Managebuilding> call, Response <Managebuilding> response) {

         if (response != null && response.code ( ) == 200 && response.isSuccessful ( )) {
               Managebuilding building = response.body ();
                            
               String Lists=new Gson ( ).toJson (response.body ());
               //  JSONArray jsonArray=new JSONArray ();
               // JSONObject jsonObject = null;
               try {
                    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject (Lists);
                    JSONArray result = jsonObject.getJSONArray ("list");
                    System.out.println (result);
                    //JSONArray result = jsonArray.getJSONArray ("ID");
                                    
                    arrayList = new ArrayList <> ();
                                    
                    for (int i = 0; i <result.length(); i++) {
                                        
                        String id=result.getJSONObject (i).getString ("ID");
                        String name =result.getJSONObject (i).getString ("Name");
                                        
                        // here you have create object of building using id and name
                        Building building = new Building(id, name)
                        buildingList.add(building);

                        arrayList.add(name);
                                        
                       }

                       ArrayAdapter <String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter <String> (getContext (),android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, arrayList);

                       adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

                       spinner.setAdapter(adapter);

                    }catch (JSONException e) {
                         e.printStackTrace ( );
                     }


                   progressDialog.dismiss ( );
               } else {
                    progressDialog.dismiss ( );
                    Log.d ("Response errorBody", String.valueOf (response.errorBody ( )));
                 }

              }


                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(Call<Managebuilding> call, Throwable t) {
                        // lv.setAdapter (adapter);
                        System.out.println("onFailure");
                        System.out.println(t.fillInStackTrace());
                        progressDialog.dismiss();
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity (), "Some error occurred -> ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();;
                        // progressDialog.dismiss();



                    }

                });
            }
```

Now you have to modify your your `setOnItemSelectedListener` like following.

```
spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener () {

            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                       int position, long id) {
                // here you can retrive you building info by positon
                Building building = buildingList.get(position)
                
                 String id = building.getId();
                 String name = building.getName();
                 
                // Now you can use your id or name to do whatever you want.
                System.out.println (id);
                System.out.println (name);
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });

    }
```

Comment: @id I getting null

Comment: I followed your approach .but,I am getting id is null

Comment: it should not be `null` if you did not missing something.

Answer (score 1):

```
String selectedBuildingId="";
spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener () {

            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                       int position, long id) {
                selectedBuildingId=position; 

                // or you can get your id using your pojo class array 
                //like 'buildingList.get(position).getID();''

                yourNextSpinnerArray.add(selectedBuildingId);

                //set yourNextSpinnerArray for your next spinner

            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

It sounds good about "Nice umang" answer.
For me, I look beyond that, I go deep on that.
I have built a class `BaseTextSpinnerAdapter<T> extends ArrayAdapter`
and I have override method `getItemId` and make it return what I want.

```
 @Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    if (mItems.get(position) != null) {
        return mItems.get(position).getObjectId();
    }
    return -1;
}
```